# bootstrap clock picker issue need a space between the time and am

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

After selection of bootstrap clock picker it showing 02:52AM,
But we need 02:52 AM

Please help anyone.
Thanks, for viewing my issue.

Comment: Share your working code

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value on `change` event, check my code sample.

> Note:  I am suggesting you to use default library behavior, if no provision for customization.

```js
var input = $('.clockpicker');
var clockpicker = input.clockpicker({
    twelvehour:true    
});

clockpicker.on('change', function(){
 var clockval = $(this).val();
  if(clockval){
    $(this).val(clockval.replace(/(?=.{2}$)/,' '));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.css">


<div class="container">
    <input class="clockpicker" value="" data-default="">
     <input class="clockpicker" value="" data-default="">
</div>
```